# either and repetition of a noun

Tags: word-choice

Is one of this sentence wrong?

> This situation creates either **arguments** for and **arguments** against putting animals behind bars.
>
> This situation creates either **arguments** for and against putting animals behind bars.

This first example looks somehow better to me, but I don't know if second "arguments" isn't redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is acceptable: *either* requires *or*, not *and*. What you probably mean is ***both*** .. and.

In either case, however, the leading term (*both* or *either*) should be placed to take **parallel** constructions in its scope:

> The situation creates ***both arguments for*** and **arguments against** X   *or*
>   The situation creates arguments ***both for*** and **against** X.
>
> The situation creates ***either arguments for*** or **arguments against** X   *or*
>   The situation creates arguments ***either for*** or **against** X.